# Molusce crashes QGIS when starting the changes raster calculation

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, land-use, molusce

I am doing a simulation of land cover changes with Molusce 3.0.13 in QGIS 2.18.9.
I am using 2 Corine landmap uses (2006 and 2012, with minor changes on the area, 12 same categories in both), road distances, sewer distances and a population net. All rasters have the same resolution (10) and are Int32 and have the same nodata value of 99999. The CRS is EPSG:3912.
The plugin calculates me the Paerson's Correlation coefficients and the Area Changes table but it crashes after starting the "create changes map".
I was trying to troubleshoot a lot (ot change, .QGIS folder deletion, plugin reinstall, different clips, nodata values...), but I could not find any remedy. I just saw that the plugin crashes later if I add a different color palette, but not sure it's relevant.
I found [this](https://github.com/nextgis/molusce/issues/9) topic open on it's Github Issues page, but there are no replies...

Does anyone know what's wrong with my data / which library I miss /etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the reclassification of values!

After searching the answer also on YouTube I got responded by a user which wrote me:

> An additional tip: a friend had labeled categories in their map with
>   numbers 101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203, 301, 302, 303, and Molusce was
>   crashing. We found that reclassifying the categories to small numbers:
>   1, 2, 3, ..., 8, 9, solved the issue.

Check his tutorial as well, this is actually a great tool!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7hoBTKhldE&t