# Why Molusce Plugin in QGIS don't show the are change, and it crash when i start the prediction?

Tags: qgis-plugins, molusce

I use QGIS 2.18.9 Las Palmas to run MOLUSCE plugin, but there are some issues when I used it. First, it doesn't show the area changes after I click the "Update Tables" button. The second issue is it always crashes when I start the Cellular Automata simulation. I need some help for resolved this issues.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243651/63384) maybe it will you a hint.

Comment: I've try that, but it's not solved my problem